# Observing test failure messages

Tags: boost-test

I am using `boost test` within a home-grown GUI, and want to access test results (e.g. the failure message and location when a test fails)

The `unit_test::test_observer` class provides the virtual method:

```
void assertion_result(boost::unit_test::assertion_result)
```

However, `unit_test::assertion_result` is just an enum indicating success or failure. From there, I cannot see how to access further information about the test result.

The framework also provides the class `test_tools::assertion_result`, which encapsulates an error message, but this only appears to be used for evaluating pre-conditions. (I would have expected this type to be the argument to `unit_test::test_observer::assertion_result`).

The log output classes appear to provide more information on test results. These are implemented as streams, which makes it non-trivial to extract test result data.

Does anyone know how I can access the information on test results - success/failure, the test code, the location, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an observer will not give you the level of details you need.

From [this class](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/unit_test_log_t.html) you can add your own formatter using the [add_formatter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/unit_test_log_t.html#idm46279112628912-bb) function. This will contain the details of what is happening and where, depending on the formatter log level.

Comment: Thanks Raffi, looks like just what I need.